# Spring Boot *.hbm.xml mapping files not loaded in test

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, hibernate-mapping

The problem is hard to explain, so please have a look at the project: https://github.com/darzz/boot_bug
This is the minimal setup, that reproduces the bug.

**Description**:
The application stack is Spring Boot with Spring Data and Spring Batch.
There is *testNamedQuery.hbm.xml* file under *src/main/resources/queries*.

When running from ***Application*** class the batch job finishes successfully, no exceptions in logs. However, when running from ***ApplicationNotWorking*** class, which is exact copy, just put in test source root, the batch job fails:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Named query not known: findPersonNames
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.getNamedQuery(AbstractSessionImpl.java:177) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.springframework.batch.item.database.HibernateItemReaderHelper.createQuery(HibernateItemReaderHelper.java:146) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.item.database.HibernateItemReaderHelper.getForwardOnlyCursor(HibernateItemReaderHelper.java:123) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.item.database.HibernateCursorItemReader.doOpen(HibernateCursorItemReader.java:185) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.item.support.AbstractItemCountingItemStreamItemReader.open(AbstractItemCountingItemStreamItemReader.java:144) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    ... 39 common frames omitted
```

**So it looks like** that when running tests, *.hbm.xml files are not loaded!
After research and debugging, I think, I might have found the cause - persistence unit root url is set for tests to target/test-classes, but the mapping files are in /target/classes.

**Possible cause** in my opinion may be similar to what's described in here http://blog.carbonfive.com/2007/05/17/using-classpath-vs-classpath-when-loading-spring-resources/

But I have no idea, how to solve this issue in Spring Boot, without creating persistence.xml configuration just for testing purposes. Don't want to copy *.hbm.xml files from main/resources to test/resources either.

Does anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@Autowired
private ResourceLoader rl;


@Bean
public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() throws IOException {
    LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactoryBean = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
    sessionFactoryBean.setMappingLocations(loadResources());
    return sessionFactoryBean;
}

public Resource[] loadResources() {
    Resource[] resources = null;
    try {
        resources = ResourcePatternUtils.getResourcePatternResolver(rl)
            .getResources("classpath:/hibernate/*.hbm.xml");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return resources;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood the problem correctly, You want to run Spring Boot Test which should pick up *.hbm files from classpath.

Where did you keep your *.hbm files?

**You have to ensure that all *.hbm files are kept under src/main/resources.** Hence when you run test class which will call the actual class which refers to *.hbm files from src/main/resources.

If above solution does not help then you need to share your project file structure.

Comment: Hi, thank you for answer. I've created a minimal project, that reproduces the issue and put it on github - please have a look (the original question got edited). For me this is some weird stuff, but I just started my journey with spring boot...

Comment: Are you making Restful service? you need to use Integration testing for Spring boot. In-spite of create springbootapplication class for test; you need to create test class using @RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class) & @SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = AppMain.class )

Comment: No, just spring batch application, wan't to make end to end tests with local database, but the *.hbm.xml files are not loading, even if I use, what you suggested.

Answer (score 0):

I looked into the git project. It seems you need to change the ApplicationNotWorking.java since it is a test class hence should be something as below:

//src/test/java

```
package bug;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired; 
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;
import com.stackoverflow.springboot.BatchProcessing;

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = Application.class )
public class ApplicationNotWorking {
    //Inject required bean which you want to test.
    @Autowired
    private BatchProcessing bProcess;
    //If above @Autowired BatchProcessing  do not work then you can object  
    //directly to kick off the test. BatchProcessing bProcess = new 
    //BatchProcessing();    

    //This way you can test each method
    @Test
    public void testBatchProcessing(){
        System.out.println("***BatchProcessing: " + bProcess.batchProcess());
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for an answer, but this still doesn't solve the problem with not loading *.hbm.xml file.